# Excel list IDs with different values

Tags: excel

I am trying to  setup an excel sheet but I am not too familiar.

I am looking to list only IDs in to Column D where the value 1 is over 50% and the value 2 is under 10% or both values equal 0,00%. If the criterias do not apply, leave the cell empty. Compare values only from same row as ID's row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell D2 and copied down:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2=0,C2=0),AND(B2>0.5,C2<0.1)),A2,"")
```

Or if your version of Excel uses semicolons as the argument delimiter instead of commas:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2=0;C2=0);AND(B2>0.5;C2<0.1));A2;"")
```